# Difference between thread user time and thread cpu time in Java

Tags: java, jmx

The ThreadMXBean has two methods for retrieving thread time usage:

- [getThreadUserTime](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadUserTime%28long%29)
- [getThreadCpuTime](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadCpuTime%28long%29)

What is the difference between the two?

---

**Update 2**: If I'm able to link to the javadocs, *please* don't quote them - I've read them already.

**Update**: here's some code which I tried to use to learn what these times mean, with little success:

```
ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
threadMXBean.setThreadContentionMonitoringEnabled(true);
long mainThreadId = getMainThreadId(threadMXBean);

logTimes("Start", threadMXBean, mainThreadId);

URL url = new URL("https://hudson.dev.java.net");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

connection.getContent();

logTimes("After loading", threadMXBean, mainThreadId);
```

and the output is:

```
Start Tue Jun 16 16:13:40 EEST 2009 Cpu time : 80, user time: 60, waited: 0, blocked: 0
After loading Tue Jun 16 16:13:43 EEST 2009 Cpu time : 1,020, user time: 960, waited: 0, blocked: 0
```

So the difference between cpu and user time increased from 20 to 60 milliseconds. Is that because using a HttpUrlConnection does include some network I/O?

Comment: I updated my post to include more info on what the values mean under WIN32.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the API docs you linked to yourself already point out

**getThreadCpuTime**

> If the implementation distinguishes
>   between user mode time and system mode
>   time, the returned CPU time is the
>   amount of time that the thread has
>   executed in user mode or system mode.

If the implementation of the JVM distinguishes between user mode and kernel mode time there could be a difference in the results of the two functions.

Further the value is only precise to the nanosecond and the value has an overflow problem if the offset is > 2^63. The JVM must also support measuring the CPU time for the current thread and it must be enabled.

On Win32 the return values should be the same as the ones you get from the [GetThreadTimes Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683237(VS.85).aspx)

`getThreadUserTime()` -> `lpUserTime * 100` //or something like this

`getThreadCpuTime()` -> `(lpKernelTime + lpUserTime) * 100` //or something like this

And a more clear reference to [User Mode vs Kernel Mode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/User_Mode_vs_Kernel_Mode)

Comment: And the difference between user mode and system mode would be 'Java code' vs. ... what?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_mode so in other words, system mode = time spent running OS and kernel-level processes, user mode = time spent running code that's a part of your application

Comment: Why there is the multiplication of 100?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Because the Win32 `GetThreadTimes` function returns timing information as `100-nanosecond units`. I tried to explain the difference between `getThreadUserTime` and `getThreadCpuTime` by comparing it to return values of the `GetThreadTimes` function

Answer (score -1):

It's explained in the javadocs :-).

> getThreadCpuTime: 
>   Returns the total CPU time for a thread of the specified ID.
>
> getThreadUserTime:
>   Returns the CPU time that a thread of the specified ID has executed in user mode.

The difference is that getThreadCpuTime also includes time that the thread used the CPU but was not in user mode. That would be things like being inside a device driver, polling for I/O or similar.

Comment: Unless you can prove otherwise (then I'll vote up), it seems your answer is misleading. On my own measurements, delta of `getThreadUserTime` calls have larger values than `getThreadCpuTime`, which contradicts your answer.

Comment: @HendyIrawan: Yes, that's strange and contradicts my answer. However, my answer is what is documented officially, and I have never seen the phenomenon you describe, so I stand by it. If you get weird results from `getThreadUserTime`, consider asking a separate question.

Comment: @HendyIrawan: Also note that the top-voted, accepted answer says the same, namely that `getThreadUserTime`<= `getThreadCpuTime`.